# Rails adding element to one-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, one-to-many, models

I have one-to-many relation between albums and posts:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :album

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
```

In `AlbumsController`, I would like to create a method for adding post to this relation (to `Album.posts`):

```
def add_post
    @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    params['album']['post_ids'].each do |post_id|
      @album.posts << Post.find(post_id)
    end
end
```

Why doesn't it work? What is the correct way of doing this? I've also tried assigning `@album.id` to the `album_id` column of the post, but it doesn't do anything either.

Form looks like this:

```
    <%= form_for :album, url: album_add_post_path(@album), method: :patch do |f| %>  
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>  
            <%= check_box_tag :post_ids, post.id, @album.posts.include?(post), :name => 'album[post_ids][]' %>  
       <% end %>  
        <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-success"%>  
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you paste the `form` you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nested attributes, like you are, You don't necesarily have to loop through the associated posts to create. ( that is what the nested attributes is for )

However, you have to ensure that you are permitting these `post_id`s in the parameters. *This is one of the most common mistakes ( I have made this a few times myself )*

So, in your controller:

```
def add_post
  @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
  @album.update(album_params)
end
```

Where the `album_params` method is as follow:

```
def album_params
  params.require(:album).permit(..., ..., ..., posts_attributes: [:id, ..., ...])
end
```

***The important things to note here:***

1. the posts_attributes comes in as an array of the attributes for all the associated attributes ( `posts_attributes: []` )
2. the `id` should be permitted for associated attributes, or else new associations will always be created each time there is an edit/update
3. all attributes of the parent object ( album ) needed to be allowed are listed directly in the permit block ( `params.require(:album).permit(..., ...,` )
4. all attributes of the child object ( post ) needed to be allowed are listed in the nested attributes block. ( `posts_attributes: [:id, ..., ...]` )

> NOTE: The front-end view form has to be set right as well. [An example can be found on this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), And you can [check the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) for more information on this.

I just saw your update with the front-end view. You can leverage the nested attributes you are already using and that I've explained by extending the album's post as follow:

```
<%= f.fields_for :posts do |p| %>
  <%= p.collection_select :post_id, Post.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: He's not using nested attributes

Comment: @RichPeck but I think he is. it is right there on the question. `accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts` inside the Album's model

Comment: If he wants to *create* new posts for the album then yep he'd have to use it; if he wants to change which posts are in an album, then he doesn't need.

Comment: "I would like to create a method for adding post to this relation"

Comment: And you will agree that  " adding post to this relation" is essentially updating the Album.

Comment: Yep of course; if he wanted to add a *new* post, he'd have to pass the new object through the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method; if just adding existing posts, he'd need to populate the `post_ids: []` attribute of the `Album` model, hence no need for nested

Comment: I'm not disputing your answer, just whether it's applicable. Someone updated it over mine, so maybe it's right :)

Comment: I just want to add existing posts to the album (even if they already belong to another album - in this case, I want to override the foreign key value - I want them to belong only to one album).

Comment: Then you can use a `collection_select`. I just updated my answer with an example of how to hook the `collection_select` with `field_for`

Answer (score 0):

The direct fix for your code is...

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :albums do
   match :posts, via: [:get, :patch], on: :member #-> url.com/albums/:id/posts
end

#app/controllers/albums_controller.rb
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
   def posts
       @album = Album.find params[:id]
       @posts = Post.all if request.get?
       if request.patch?
         @album.update album_params
         @album.save
       end
   end 

   private

   def album_params
       params.require(:album).permit(post_ids: [])
   end
end
```

This can be accompanied with a `collection_select`:

```
#app/views/albums/posts.html.erb
<%= form_for @album do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :post_ids, @posts, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**However**, this will *not* work (I presume) as you'd hope.

When using `belongs_to` / `has_many`, you can only have matching "pairs" of relations. This means that adding to the [`singular_collection_ids`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord%2FAssociations%2FClassMethods%3Ahas_many) method will override any existing `belongs_to` reference in the `Post` records.

In short, if you want to *change* (not add) your associated objects, it will work. If you want to *add* existing `posts` to an `album`, you'll have to use the code below.

---

You'd be best using [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :album do
   resources :posts #-> url.com/albums/:album_id/posts/new 
end

#app/models/album.rb
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end 

#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :albums
end

#app/controllers/albums_controller.rb
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
    def edit
       @album = Album.find params[:id]
       @posts = Post.all
    end

    def update
       @album = Album.find params[:id]
       @album.update album_params
    end

    private

    def album_params
       params.require(:album).permit(post_ids: [])
    end
end

#app/views/albums/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @album do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :post_ids, @posts, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When I try to do the direct fix (I don't mind overriding the belongs_to reference if the post already belongs to another album), I'm getting this error: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to replace posts because one or more of the new records could not be saved.):
  app/controllers/albums_controller.rb:51:in `posts`

Comment: OK, I am not even able to change album.posts or post.album_id in rails console if it's already set (if it's not set yet, it's possible). Is there a way how to do it? (I don't really want post to belong to more than one album, that's why I tried the first version of your code, I want to override the existing association).

Comment: Yes but you need to answer my last question; which of my solutions have you used?

Comment: #config/routes.rb
resources :albums do
   match :posts, via: [:get, :patch], on: :member #-> url.com/albums/:id/posts
end
...